# Did I just create a Debian/Kali hybrid? And should I be worried?

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I installed Debian 9 today, configured it and decided to get some pentesting tools. I found this thing called [katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin).

What it did was added Kali's repos to my sources.list. And then I forgot that I added them. And I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`... And it went for 10 min, grabbed over 600 items from Kali's repo, and stopped. But when I restarted the machine I saw that suddenly the grub background is Kali, and the name of the machine in GRUB is Kali.

The system works, I can do programming and so on, it doesn't bother me personally. But for safety and everything should I reinstall Debian/roll back the `apt-get` (if it's doable)?

Comment: Be very worried, distribution ninjas are making their way to your home to roll things back permanently!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s rather unfortunate (and a nasty bug in the tool you used, really). The result might work fine, but you could have issues with future upgrades; since Kali is a rolling distribution, I’d expect it to diverge from Debian 9 as times goes by.

Since you only installed Debian today, I’d just re-install it, that will be the simplest solution. There’s no easy way to roll back an `apt-get` operation.

For future reference:

- `apt-get upgrade` would have shown you what it was going to do, and asked for confirmation; in Debian 9, seeing a huge list of packages there is an indication that something is wrong and you should stop and investigate;
- there’s no need to do an `upgrade` if you’re going to `dist-upgrade` anyway (the latter is a superset of the former) ...
- but generally speaking you shouldn’t need to `dist-upgrade` in Debian 9 (as its name suggests, it’s designed to upgrade a full distribution, *e.g.* when you upgrade to Debian 10).

Comment: >but generally speaking you shouldn’t need to dist-upgrade in Debian 9 (as its name suggests, it’s designed to upgrade a full distribution, e.g. when you upgrade to Debian 10).

I thought this is like a update in security and so on.

So there is not going to be any security problems? I already commented out the Kali repos.

Comment: No, there won’t be security problems; `apt-get upgrade` is sufficient for those.

Comment: it turned out, I was unable to install any compilers. Maybe I was doing smth wrong, but I switched to Fedora for now. We'll see how this works out